# Apex Test class code coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test

Not getting coverage on these line of code, can anyone help with the test class?

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static Boolean deleteRecord(Id recordId){
    Sobject sobj = recordId.getSObjectType().newSObject(recordId);
    Database.DeleteResult result = Database.delete(sobj, true);
return result.isSuccess();
```

}

```
public with sharing class SingleRelatedListController {
public static final String FIELDS_PARAM = 'fields';
public static final String NUMBER_OF_RECORDS_PARAM = 'numberOfRecords';
public static final String RECORD_ID_PARAM = 'recordId';
public static final String SOBJECT_API_NAME_PARAM = 'sobjectApiName';
public static final String SOBJECT_LABEL_PARAM = 'sobjectLabel';
public static final String SOBJECT_LABEL_PLURAL_PARAM = 'sobjectLabelPlural';
public static final String PARENT_RELATIONSHIP_API_NAME_PARAM = 'parentRelationshipApiName';
public static final String RELATED_FIELD_API_NAME_PARAM = 'relatedFieldApiName';
public static final String SORTED_DIRECTION_PARAM = 'sortedDirection';
public static final String SORTED_BY_PARAM = 'sortedBy';
public static final String RECORDS_PARAM = 'records';
public static final String ICON_NAME_PARAM = 'iconName';

@AuraEnabled
public static List<RecordType> getRecordTypes(String objectName) {
    List<RecordType> rts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = :objectName];
    return rts;
}

public static String findObjectNameFromRecordIdPrefix(String recordIdOrPrefix){
    String objectName = '';
    try{
        //Get prefix from record ID
        //This assumes that you have passed at least 3 characters
        String myIdPrefix = String.valueOf(recordIdOrPrefix).substring(0,3);

        //Get schema information
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd =  Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 

        //Loop through all the sObject types returned by Schema
        for(Schema.SObjectType stype : gd.values()){

            //if (!sObj.contains('__')) to exclude managed package objects

            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = stype.getDescribe();
            String prefix = r.getKeyPrefix();
            System.debug('Prefix is ' + prefix);

            //Check if the prefix matches with requested prefix
            if(prefix!=null && prefix.equals(myIdPrefix)){
                objectName = r.getName();
                System.debug('Object Name! ' + objectName);
                break;
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.debug(e);
    }
    return objectName;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first insert the test records in a @testSetup method and query for the inserted records form test method and call the orginal methods providing the  record Id